# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.CertificateLoader'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, certificate, .net-6.0, kestrel

While migrating from .net461 to .net6.0 and along with migrating from Entity Framework to Entity Framework Core, getting following error while loading a certificate

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.CertificateLoader'` from assembly `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=6.0.0.0`

I don't have anything specified for the version 6.0.0.0. Is this version coming from some runtime assembly?

I also have removed the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core` from my code but still it finds it somehow

Comment: Hi @abhishek jagwani, could you pls share your project file?